# howto create two git repo (dev and production) at one vps

Tags: git, vps, dev-to-production

sorry for my english.

**i have:** VPS, installed git, web application is hosted at the following path: /var/www/%username%/data/
the structure of the application:

```
/app/
/www/
--/site.com/
--/dev.site.com/
```

**task:** make  a test server (dev.site.com) and productions server (site.com), test repo is for coding, and then pushing in production repo, using git.

**problem:** I do not understand how and where do I store the two local repository. test repo must displayed on dev.site.com, I could work in it, and then push it in production repo, which is displayed on site.com

I think that I will need to have two copies of the folder /app/ for each of the repositories, and two public folders /site.com/ and /dev.site.com/ same for each of the repositories, something like this:

```
/app/dev/ or /app-dev/
/app/prod/ or /app-prod/
/www/site.com/
/www/dev.site.com/
```

**question:** how and where do I initialize each of the repositories for such a structure, and how to add each of them only a fitting directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and follow this tutorial : http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2012/11/20/do-yourself-a-favor-set-up-a-staging-server/

It's very well put together.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: Apologies, this part of the rules must have escaped me. I will do so when I have a bit more time.